# PHP: Query retrieving first and some empty rows

Tags: php, mysql, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
while ($var1 == $var2)
{
    $sql = “SELECT disabled FROM MYTABLE WHERE VAR2=’$var2’”;
    $r = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

My problem is that $sql retrieves ten rows: 4 of them have data, the rest are empty.

As the first row is empty the second while is never entered.

But I need it to be entered, what do I have to do?

In the example code I'm using MySQL but I can use TSQL.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem because `mysql_fetch_assoc()` should never return null.

Comment: That's not your real code, right?  You have invalid curly quotes all over the place. Those should be proper `"` and `'`

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() is a deprecated php extension. You should try using mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah it looks to be some craze UTF quotes.

Comment: @florin: gee, and you think mysqli_fetch_assoc will work with a query performed with mysql_query?

Comment: Cthulhu, you're right, I didn't mean NULL I meant EMPTY rows .. sorry for that. I can use TSQL also, is there any solution using TSQL? Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the total rows first.

```
while (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Sorry that will not work, try the below.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) 
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the extra check needed? If no rows were returned, the while-loop will terminate immediately, since `mysql_fetch_assoc` (and the analogous mysqli and PDO functions) returns `false` when it reaches the end of the results.

Comment: The if condition first checks if rows exist. If yes, then only the while loop executes.

Comment: The same thing will happen if you don't do the check, won't it? The while condition will be false immediately, so it won't execute the loop.

Comment: The only time I would do the num rows check is if I wanted to do something in its `else` clause, such as displaying "No results found".

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But we are not allowing the while condition to execute unless we know that it has rows in it. Why should the while condition become false ? If its false we dont allow it to execute. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It does not work, sorry, the while is never entered .. there are rows but the first one is empty and the loop stops there ..

Answer (score 0):

if you're having problems when "mysql_query" is resulting nothing, just put a conditional:

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($result && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // do something
}
```

the manual says ... [mysql-fetch-assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)  *"Use of this extension is discouraged"*